# How To Add GCP Service Account To Kubernetes Workload/Project

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, account, bucket

I am attempting to add a GCP service account Y that has access to a specific storage bucket named 'security-keychain'. I'm trying to figure out what config or changes are necessary to make my current project capable of accessing said service account and then the bucket.

I did look over https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/ but didn't feel like it provided much insight.

Here are my current GCP Kubernetes config for this project. My project will be a nginx reverse proxy, in case you're wondering, and the bucket has access to all the SSL certificates and keys I need.

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: my-project
  name: my-project
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-project
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: my-project
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/my-company/my-project
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: my-project
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "800m"
            memory: 4Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: 2Gi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 443
          protocol: TCP
        securityContext:
           capabilities: {}
           privileged: true
           capabilities:
            add:
              - SYS_ADMIN
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["gcsfuse", "-o", "nonempty", "security-keychain", "/mnt/security-keychain"]
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["fusermount", "-u", "/mnt/security-keychain"]
```

service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-project-service # service name
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer # gives your app a public IP so the outside world can get to it
  loadBalancerIP: 99.99.99.99 # declared in VPC Networks > External IP Addresses in GCP Console
  ports:
    - port: 80 # port the service listens on
      targetPort: 80 # port the app listens on
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
    - port: 443 # port the service listens on
      targetPort: 443 # port the app listens on
      protocol: TCP
      name: https
  selector:
    run: my-project
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform#step_3_create_service_account_credentials) to archive your goal if your architecture implies that you must use a service account.Keep in mind that you can mount directly a Kubernetes pod/container to a Google Cloud Storage bucket following this other [guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/7890)